# VBA :: Not getting the record count from the ADODB RecordSet

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have run the below query manually in ACCESS DataBase we are getting the total record count for the query.

Query:
`SELECT Count(ID) FROM Reports WHERE Active = 1 And CustomerName like 'Test*' And CreatedDate >= #25-06-2023# And CreatedDate <= #05-02-2024#`

But for the below VBA code we are getting zero as the value after executing the below code.
Code:

```
`Dim objReprtRecsetCnt As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cntqry
 cntqry = "SELECT Count(ID) FROM Reports WHERE Active = 1 And CustomerName like '" + CStr(nameStartsWithLetter) + "' And CreatedDate >= #" + CStr(fromDate) + "# And CreatedDate <= #" + CStr(toDate) + "#"
 
 With objReprtRecsetCnt
     .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
     .Source = cntqry
     .LockType = adLockReadOnly
     .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
     .Open
 End With
  
 cnt = objReprtRecsetCnt.Fields.Item(0).Value
 objReprtRecsetCnt.Close`
```

I tried to execute the code with out the CustomerName it is fetching the record count. But i need to get the count with the CustomerName.

Below code:

`cntqry = "SELECT Count(ID) FROM Reports WHERE Active = 1 And CreatedDate >= #" + CStr(fromDate) + "# And CreatedDate <= #" + CStr(toDate) + "#"`

I tried to replace + with & but still it is showing zero as the result after executing the code.

Comment: Is `nameStartsWithLetter` a variable? Does it contain the wildcard character?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `CursorLocation` to `adUseClient` may be of help here.
https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_rs_cursorlocation.asp

Comment: @shashkalpesh i have tried with different combinations of the Cursorlocation but the result is getting as zero only.

Comment: @SunilG.V.: Try removing the cursor type/lock type property that you are setting. I am sorry, I dont have MS-Access to try things out.

Comment: i tried to run only with the below query but not getting value from the code execution   ''' cntqry = "SELECT Count(ID) FROM Reports WHERE CustomerName like '" + CStr(nameStartsWithLetter) + "'" '''

Comment: i tried to remove the cursor type/lock type proeperties but no use not getting the value.

Comment: @SunilG.V.: Do you get the count of records when you run the query in access? Are you connecting to the *same* db? Does your connection string point to the exact same path where your access database is?

Comment: yes we are getting the result when we run the same query in the MS Access manually. 
SELECT Count(ID)
FROM Reports
WHERE CustomerName like 'A*';

Answer (score 0):

Instead of * i used the % the issue is resolved.

'''SELECT Count(ID) FROM Reports WHERE Active = 1 And CustomerName like 'Test%' And CreatedDate >= #25-06-2023# And CreatedDate <= #05-02-2024#'''